# General behaviour of concatenation

Tags: perl, concatenation, system-calls

I am trying to run pdflatex as a system call from a Perl script.
Like said in [Using system()](http://www.perlhowto.com/executing_external_commands) one should execute an external programm with `system("command", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3");` to run it directly and avoid opening a subshell. When I do so with

```
system("pdflatex", "LaTexFile", ">& stdout.txt") == 0 or die "pdflatex failed with exit code $?";
```

the output isn't written to the `stdout.txt` instead it is printed to the terminal (STDOUT). So I tried

```
system("pdflatex " . "LaTexFile " . ">& stdout.txt") == 0 or die "pdflatex failed with exit code $?";
```

which works.

[How to concatenate strings with Perl](http://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl010003.shtml) gives an overview how to concatenate in Perl. But it don't says what are the differences in the methods. When I am defining stuff I usually do it like `my $var = "name_$othervar";` so I don't even use curly brackets.

Any explanation is appreciated.

Comment: `">& stdout.txt"` isn't an argument to your command (pdflatex). It is interpreted by the executing environment/shell. pdflatex cant make any use of it.

Comment: The first call to `system` is not an example of string concatenation, but rather a list of arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You  answered  your own  question.  *"to  run  directly  and avoid  opening  a
subshell"*. The `>&` is a shell syntax  which is not interpreted if you're not
using a shell to execute that command.

The  second case  works  since  that's the  behaviour  when  passing a  single
argument to `system()` (opening  a shell). By the way, take a look on what the
page that you linked to says:

> `system()` accepts as argument either a  scalar or an array. If the argument
>   is a  scalar, `system()` uses  a shell to  execute the command  (`/bin/sh -c
>   command`); if the argument is an array it executes the command directly,